# If $\log(ax)\log(bx) +1=0$ has a solution $x>0$, then find bounds on $b/a$

Tags: logarithms

> If equation $$\log(ax)\log(bx) +1=0$$ with constants $\;a>0,\; b>0\;$
>   has a solution $x>0$, it follows that $$\frac{b}{a} \ge ???$$
>   or $$???\ge\frac{b}{a}\gt???$$
>
> Fill all in the blank.

To be honest, I am very lost here and not sure how I can get into $\frac{b}{a}$ part. The answers provided were $100, 1/100,\;$  and $\;0\;$ respectively.

I would like to hear the perspective of how other people think about this problem. Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: The expression is symmetric in $a,b$.  Whatever inequality hold for $\frac ba$ must also hold for $\frac ab$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

The equation can be rewritten as $$(\log a + \log x))(\log b+ \log x) +1=0.$$ Set $t=\log x$ and expand, the obtained  quadratic equation $$t^2+t(\log a + \log b) + \log a \cdot \log b +1=0.$$
The discriminant $D=(\log {a\over b}-2)(\log {a\over b}+2)$ must satisfy  $$(\log {a\over b}-2)(\log {a\over b}+2)\geq 0$$ if we want real  solutions. Can you finish it from this?

Comment: Thank you for your hint! Continuing from you would get $$(\log\frac{a}{b})^2\ge4$$
 where $\frac{a}{b}>0$

case 1:$$\log\frac{a}{b}\le-2$$
$$\frac{a}{b}\le10^{-2}$$
Hence 
$$0<\frac{a}{b}\le10^{-2}$$

case 2: $$\log\frac{a}{b}\ge2$$
$$\frac{a}{b}\ge100$$

Comment: Nice, I am glad I could help and you could finish it.

Comment: $D = (\log a + \log b)^2 - 4(\log a. \log b. + 1)$ how is it ended up $(\log \frac ab )^2 - 4$ ?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter  $D = (\log a + \log b)^2 - 4(\log a. \log b. + 1)=(\log a)^2+2\log a \log b + (\log b)^2-4\log a \log b -4=(\log a - \log b)^2 -4$

Comment: Btw, there are many possibilities for a and b ?

Comment: sure, @Lifeforbetter

Comment: And a solution means?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It is $$(\ln(x))^2+\ln(x)(\ln(a)+\ln(b))+\ln(a)\ln(b)+1=0$$ it is a quadratic in $$\ln(x)$$.

Comment: It is very useful, thank you for your hint!